# Re-install old HP Deskjet 460 portable printer

Tags: internet-explorer, drivers, printer

I have an old but useful printer - HP DeskJet 460, circa 2003 (not the same as a more recent 460 printer from HP!) but since I had to re-initialized Windows, I need to install a driver for the printer.

Unfortunately, my Windows 10 pro 64bit OS doesn't have the driver; it tells me to go to the HP website. The HP website tells me to use the Windows driver.

Fortunately I have the original HP CD (from 2007) for this printer. However, when beginning installation of the driver from the disk I get the message
Setup error - Internet Exploerer 5.0 or later required.
But when I ask Google, it of course directs me to Microsoft, but Microsoft no longer has IE on offer, only Edge!

There's an Edge setting to masquerade as IE. But that doesn't fool the HP 460 installer setup.

Is there an out to this dead end?

Comment: The information from HP is likely correct, i.e., it should work with the driver already included in the current Windows 10/11 versions. Trying to install an old driver (for XP!!!) won't work for obvious reasons. I suggest you simply connect the printer and try to use it. Again, it should work if HP says it's now supported out-of-the-box. If it doesn't then it doesn't, get yourself a current product.

Comment: Windows 10 recognizes that the printer is plugged in and explicitly denies having a drive for the it; says I must obtain it from HP. So HP & Windows disclaim responsibility in exactly symmetrical fashion.

Comment: Buying a new printer is not a prohibitive expense, but it's hard to learn before purchase if it will serve my purpose of printing close to the edge of a non-standard (namely bank check) piece of paper.

Comment: You may try an Ubuntu virtual machine or dual-boot.

Comment: The old XP driver is compatible with Windows 10, for I was able to install it 3 years ago. What has changed is the availability of IE. Three years ago I had it on my computer. If there were a sourse to let me install it today I'd be in clover.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually solved this issue after over 2 hours of brainstorming on it.

When you connect the printer, you will get the error message that drivers are incorrect, ignore this and remove the printer in the printers window.

1. Download the old Windows XP drivers(f.e. https://fs4.softfamous.com/downloads/tname-151122dld037/software/DJ460_WinXP64_EN.exe)
2. Extract it to folder on Desktop.
3. In printers and scanners, go for add printer, then printer wasn't listed. There choose Add a local printer, choose existing port USB001, on the next screen click on button Have Disk, there find extracted files on Desktop and choose .inf file. Restart your computer after adding and voilla it should be working.
   Hope this will help atleast one person in the future, because having year 2003 printer doesn't mean to dump it :)

Comment: Thanks Marek. This looks like gold. I overlooked this when you posted though, and now the fs4.softmaous... like you gave doesn't respond. So I tried searching just for the last part - "DJ460 ... exe" - and there are plenty of hits. I tried a couple, downloaded, but instead of the advertised file name including the printer "DJ460 ..." I get something generic like outbyte-driver-updater.exe, which, when executed (on a computer that I don't depend on for business) promises to clean up my computer especially for a small contribution.

Comment: I hope for advice about whether or which of these web sites are trustworthy (really will provide the driver one wants) and safe.

Answer (score -1):

You are welcome Charles, on link below, there is the drivers I keep downloaded in case of Windows reinstall.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-skevXHluBD-oYVrN_VvoWyU2kjTxI7y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1211472)